# Immigration agent at airport said visitor will overstay Schengen visa by 1 day

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, germany, schengen-visas, fra

We currently have visitors in Germany, at the airport one agent noted that our visitors will overstay for 1 day, but I feel like they made a mistake, but I am not sure.

I have attached the visa information and censored all personal data, it says it's valid from 28.02.2022 until 27.05.2022 (89 days). They arrived at 28.02.2022 in FRA in the morning and will leave on 27.05.2022 in the evening (departure is definitely before midnight). The agent noted they normally would have to leave on 26.05.2022. I don't quite understand where I am wrong, maybe someone can help.[image]

Comment: Did they visit the Schengen Area recently (in the last 90 days or so)? If they did they would have used part of their 90/180 allowance.

Comment: No, it's their first time in the Schengen Area.

Comment: Someone didn’t have their breakfast and forgot that February only has 28 days this year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your computation appears to be correct, as confirmed by the [Schengen calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en) provided by the EU Commission. This may be a simple mistake because a maximum length of stay of 89 days is somewhat confusing (the calculator is based on the visa-free rule of 90 days).

For the sake of completeness, note that there is no requirement that the period of validity and maximum duration of stay coincide. For example, a visa could be valid for 10 days between February 28 and May 28 and each condition has to be evaluated separately. But in this case, there really are 89 days between February 28 and May 27, including both those days.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why we only got 89 days approved by the embassy. We applied for 90 days, but we already had planned the flights with one day buffer and attached it at the application. That's when they probably took away our one day buffer because they saw the flight details, ups. But overall it seems like a mistake by the immigration agent.

Comment: My guess is you were given "3 months" for the validity period. It just so happens that there's only 89 days in those 3 months, so your maximum stay was limited to 89 days.

Comment: @Doc it's possible, but all the short-stay regulations and calculations have been expressed in terms of days for several years now.  The explanation proposed by HazyCosmic seems more likely; it would not be the first time I've heard of a consulate granting a visa based exactly on the planned dates of travel (even though they're not supposed to).